# WPF Listbox binding problems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm creating an N-tier wpf mvvm project. I want to get a list of items from the db to be displayed in a listbox.  I want to bind the listbox to a property in the ViewModel (VM).  The problem is the binding is not working for me, the listbox is always empty.
When I put a breakpoint on "return Tags" it is fully populated before the form is shown.

The `DataContext = App.ViewModel;` in the MainWindow() constructor.

In my XAML

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tags, Mode=OneWay}" Height="161" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,6,0,0" Name="lstTags" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" >
             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tags.Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tags.Description}" />
                            <!--<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Deleted, Mode=TwoWay}"/>-->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
             </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In my VM:   When I put a breakpoint on "return Tags" it is fully populated.

```
private TagCol _tags;
public TagCol Tags
{
    get {
        TagColData tcd = new TagColData();
        _tags = tcd.LoadAll();

        //NotifyPropertyChanged("Tags");

        return _tags; 
    }
    set {
        _tags = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Tags");
    }
}
```

TagCol:

public class TagCol
{
    private ObservableCollection _tagCol = new ObservableCollection();

```
/// <summary>Collection (list) of Tag objects</summary>
public ObservableCollection<Tag> Collection { 
    get { return _tagCol; } 
    set 
    { 
        _tagCol = value;
    } 
}

public TagCol()
{

}
```

}

Comment: Have you set the DataContext of the MainWindow (or any parent control of the ListBox) to an instance of your view model class?

Comment: could you please include the definition of `TagCol `

Comment: Use Snoop to examine the bindings and the controls at runtime.  TagCol must implement IEnumerable for this to work.

Comment: Hi Guys.  
I've updated the question with the TagCol class.
Clemens the DataContext is set in the MainWindow() constructor.

Comment: Snoop is interesting, although a little scary how it can mess with your app like that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys it was of course in the Binding, it needed to be set to **Tags.Collection**
Incidentally, in the sub properties for the textboxes Collection.Name won't work.

Well that took a couple of day's spare time ! :)

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tags.Collection}" Height="161" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,6,0,0" Name="lstTags" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Deleted, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```